# Every continuous function is the difference of two nonnegative continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Prove that every continuous function $f$ can be written $f = g−h$, where
>   $g$ and $h$ are nonnegative and continuous.

If I define $g=\max\{f,0\}$ and $h=\max\{0,-f\}$, do I need to prove that $g$ and $h$ are still continuous and if so how do I do that?

Comment: Technically yes, you should prove that they are continuous. What definition of continuity were you given?

Comment: Definition of continuity  For all epsilon greater than 0, there exists a delta greater than zero such that for all x satisfying |x-a|<delta implies that |f(x)-f(a)|< epsilon

Comment: Since $\max\{f,0\}=(f+|f|)/2,$ the continuity of $\max\{f,0\}$ follows from stuff you probably already know about continuity of sums and products and compositions of continuous functions, and continuity of the function $x\mapsto|x|.$

Answer (score 2):

Start by showing that $|g(x)-g(y)|\le |f(x)-f(y)|$ for all $x$ and $y$. (One way to do this is to consider the four cases determined by the signs of $f(x)$ and $f(y)$.)

One guesses such an inequality by viewing $g$ as the function composition $p\circ f$, where $p(u) = \max\{0,u\}$ is the positive part function. The graph of $p$ is a broken line with slope either $0$ or $1$.